# Aync/await workflow: what I'm doing wrong in loading and injecting this external script?

Tags: javascript, async-await

The problem is quite simple: some calls to `refresh()` result in `window.grecaptcha` to be `undefined`. Not always as I said, I think because network slowdown. It's quite "hard" to debug this, and I'm also quite new to this concept, so I'm asking for some help, maybe a code fault.

```js
class RecaptchaController {
  loadPromise;

  async refresh() {
    await this.load();
    // window.grecaptcha is (sometimes) undefined in next line
    this.element.value = window.grecaptcha.execute(this.options.siteKey, { action: 'submit' });
  }

  load() {
    if (!this.loadPromise) {
      this.context.logDebugActivity('load');

      this.loadPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const url = new URL(this.options.apiUrl);
        url.searchParams.append('render', this.options.siteKey);
        url.searchParams.append('hl', this.options.locale);

        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.setAttribute('id', this.identifier);
        script.setAttribute('src', url.toString());

        // The relevant part where I'm resolving the promise
        script.addEventListener('load', resolve);
        script.addEventListener('error', reject);

        document.body.appendChild(script);
      })
    }

    return this.loadPromise;
  }
}
```

Error thrown is:

> recaptcha_controller.js:27 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'execute')

Basically, `refresh` is going to be called in a `submit` event handler, like this:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
   // This is NOT how the initialization works!
   // Just and example about how I'm calling refresh()
   cost recaptchaController = new RecaptchaController();

   // This is actually what is happening
   await recaptchaController.refresh();

   // Submit handling via fetch()...
});
```

I'm not pasting the entire code to make it simple. In addition, there is a framework behind (but it's not relevant).

Comment: How are you calling `refresh`? That code isn't in your question.

Comment: also nowhere in the code you show us is `window.grecaptcha` defined, so we can't possibly debug any potential race conditions between that code and the code you have shared

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks, removed the image in favour of error text.

Comment: @Andy I'll update the question. How I'm calling refresh is a bit difficult because I'm using a framework. I'll try to do my best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a test with reCAPTCHA v3, and looking at requests in DevTools network panel, it seems reCAPTCHA itself loads another locale-specific script asynchronously. To dynamically load reCAPTCHA the way you're trying to, you need to setup a globally visible callback and pass its name to the `onload` parameter of `api.js`.

```js
  load() {
    if (!this.loadPromise) {
      this.context.logDebugActivity('load');

      this.loadPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // recaptcha onload will resolve this promise
        window._recaptchaOnLoad = () => resolve();

        const url = new URL(this.options.apiUrl);
        url.searchParams.append('onload', '_recaptchaOnLoad');
        url.searchParams.append('render', this.options.siteKey);
        url.searchParams.append('hl', this.options.locale);

        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.setAttribute('id', this.identifier);
        script.setAttribute('src', url.toString());

        // load event no longer needed
        script.addEventListener('error', reject);

        document.body.appendChild(script);
      }).finally(() => {
        // optionally delete window property
        delete window._recaptchaOnLoad;
      })
    }

    return this.loadPromise;
  }
```

Comment: Super nice catch. Thanks, I would never find it out, I think. I'll try your solution, even if the global window variable is so so bad :)

Comment: It's advisable to set the src attribute last, after the error (and maybe load) event listeners are registered.